# Change Image Using Pseudo Element in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass

I have a dropdown and there is an icon that changes everytime it is clicked. I coded the css styling using sass and I am not sure if I did it correctly. There were no errors on my jquery code though. I think the main problem is how I constructed my code in scss.

html

```
<div class="family-site">                       
  <div class="content">
    <span>
      <a>관련사이트</a>
    </span>
    <div class="fs-links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">고려대학교</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">KUPID</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">KURMS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">LINC플러스사업본부</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>                    
</div>
```

Jquery Code:

```
$(".content").click(function(event){

    var col=0;
    if(col==0){
        $(this).toggleClass("open");
        $(".fs-links > li:nth-child(4)").css("border-bottom", "none");
        col=1;
    } else if (col==1){
        $(this).toggleClass("content");
        col=0;
    }
        $(this).parent().find(".fs-links").first().toggle();
        $(this).parent().siblings().find(".fs-links").hide();
    });
```

SCSS Code:

```
.family-site {
float: right;
margin: 0;
    .content {
        padding: 13px 0px 6px 18px;
        background-color: #252525;
        width: 208px;
        border: 1px solid #575757;
        margin: -9px 0; 
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 19px;
            a {
                color: #fff;
                text-decoration: none;
            }           
        &:after {
            content: "";
            background-image: url(../images/icon/icon_fs_open.png);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            padding: 17px 21px 0px 16px;
            float: right;
            height: 8px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 248px;
            top: 26px;
            border-left: 1px solid #575757;
            height: 21px;
            margin: -16px 1px 1px -1px;
         }
            .open{
                &::after {
                    content: "";
                    background-image: url(../images/icon/icon_fs_close.png);
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;
                    background-position: center;
                    padding: 17px 21px 0px 16px;
                    float: right;
                    height: 8px;
                    position: absolute;
                    right: 248px;
                    top: 26px;
                    border-left: 1px solid #575757;
                    height: 21px;
                    margin: -16px 1px 1px -1px;
            }
        }

        span {
            float: left;
            margin: -4px 0;
        }
    }
    .fs-links {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: -148px;
            right: 247px;
            width: 226px;
            background-color: #343434;
            border: 1px solid #575757;
            border-bottom: none;
            cursor: ponter;
                    ul {
                        list-style: none;
                        padding: 0;
                        margin: -1px;
                        li {
                             line-height: 39px;
                             border-bottom: 1px solid #575757;
                             a {
                                color: #c9c9c9;
                                margin: 14px;
                             }
                            &:hover {
                                background-color: #575757;
                                a {
                                    color: #fff;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
        }
```

}

What I wanted the output to happen is I want to change the the arrow button up to arrow button down when on clicked. Not sure if I constructed the scss code correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your jQuery is toggling the `.open` class into the `.content` element, you are missing the `&` on the SCSS.

```
}
   &.open{
        &::after {
        ...
        }
   }
}
```